# How to call a ASPxControl using ASPxMenu's OnItemClick? C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress

I have a ASPxMenu that I have named "mnuCategoryOptions" and it has 4 items and I also have ASPxPopupControl that I have named "popupAddProductCategory". When I click one of the items in the ASPxMenu I want it to bring up the ASPxPopupControl. I have written my code in the following way and it does not work:

```
<dx:ASPxMenu ID="mnuCategoryOptions" runat="server" OnItemClick="mnuCategoryOptions_ItemClick">
                                    <ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function(s, e) 
                                    {
                                        e.processOnServer = false;

                                        if (e.item.name == 'mnuAddCategory')  { popupAddProductCategory.Show = true; }
                                        else if (e.item.name == 'mnuEditCategory')  { alert('Edit Category'); }
                                        else if (e.item.name == 'mnuDeleteCategory')  { alert('Del Category'); }
                                        else if (e.item.name == 'mnuAddProducts')  { alert('Add Products'); }
                                        else { e.processOnServer = true; }                
                                    }" />

                                    <Items>
                                        <dx:MenuItem Name="mnuAddCategory"              Text="Add Category"><Image Url="~/images/GridIcons/add.png"/></dx:MenuItem>
                                        <dx:MenuItem Name="mnuEditCategory"              Text="Edit Category"><Image Url="~/images/GridIcons/page_edit.png"/></dx:MenuItem>
                                        <dx:MenuItem Name="mnuDeleteCategory"              Text="Delete Category"><Image Url="~/images/GridIcons/delete.png"/></dx:MenuItem>
                                        <dx:MenuItem Name="mnuAddProducts"         Text="Add Products"><Image Url="~/images/GridIcons/page_add.png"  /></dx:MenuItem>                                                            
                                    </Items>
                                </dx:ASPxMenu>
```

Please look at the line "if (e.item.name == 'mnuAddCategory')  { popupAddProductCategory.Show = true; }". This is the line that is not working. Please help.

Kind Regards
Siyabonga Kubeka

Comment: What about `popupAddProductCategory.Show();`? `Show` is not a boolean property, it is a function according to DevExpress docs.

Comment: Hello Tetsuya, thank you very much for the input. I have tried popupAddProductCategory.Show(); it does not work.

Comment: What thing doesn't work? Make sure that you're setting `ClientInstanceName` with same name as popup control ID in `ASPxPopupControl` first, then find out if you encounter JS error in browser dev tools.

Comment: Thank you very much Tetsuya. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `ASPxPopupControl` server control like this:

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="popupAddProductCategory" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="popupAddProductCategory" ... />
```

Then you should use `Show()` method to show that popup with client-side code:

```
if (e.item.name == 'mnuAddCategory') { 
    popupAddProductCategory.Show(); 
}
```

According to [ASPxClientPopupControlBase member list](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientPopupControlBase.members), `Show` is name of a method, not a property. Also `ClientInstanceName` property from popup control must be used if you want to use same client-side name as control name.

Reference:

[ASPxClientPopupControlBase.Show() function](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientPopupControlBase.Show.method(ZgszxA))